# Proof of an inverse Matrix

Tags: matrix-equations

I am very raw at proofs, this is only my first semester learning them and I am having trouble with this problem. How would I approach this ?

If $$ is an $ × $ matrix that satisfies the equation $ $ is $A^3 -4A^2 +3A -5I_n = 0$, Find the $A^{-1}$

Comment: Is there anymore propety as to $A$ such as nilponent or idemponet?

Comment: @Bulbasaur it does not mention, but I think it is nilponent

Comment: It can't be nilpotent if $A^{-1}$ exists

Comment: **Hint**: Write your equation as $$A\Big(\frac{A^2-4A+3I}{5}\Big)=I$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A^3 -4A^2 +3A -5I_n = 0$$

Or,
$$5I_n = A^3 -4A^2 +3A$$

Pre-multiplying both sides by $A^{-1}$ and dividing by $5$,
$$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{5}(A^2 -4A +3I_n)$$